# Cloud function error - 'Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value'

Tags: javascript, function, firebase, cloud

I have a cloud function from which I'm sending an email. However I'm getting an error when I send the email. The email is sending successfully but it's the error 'Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value ' is showing in the console. 
I've tried adjusting the script a few times but I'm kind of struggling with where the error is coming from. I've attached my code below

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport 
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
     user: gmailEmail,
     pass: gmailPassword
   }
});

exports.checkForFails = functions.firestore
   .document('equipment/{itemId}')
   .onUpdate(event => {
         newDoc = event.data.data();
         if(newDoc.hasFailed){
             const mailOptions = {
                 from: '"Emailer" <noreply@firebase.com>',
                 to: "desination@email.com"
             };

             const userDatabase = admin.firestore().doc('users/' +  
             newDoc.user);

             userDatabase.get().then(function(snap){
                 data = snap.data();
                 mailOptions.subject = ('Text Subject' + data.subject);
                 mailOptions.text = ('Text body' + data.body);
             })
             .then(() => {
                  mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
                  .then(() => console.log('Notification sent to WFE email'))
                  .catch(error => console.log('There was an error'))
             })
             .catch(error => console.log('Couldnt send mail', + error))
        }else {
             return 0;
        }
   })
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? I am facing the same issue. Please let me know if you have any solution for this [ https://prnt.sc/do1jiSRgMInO ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function performs asynchronous work, [it needs to return a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) that's resolved when that work completes.

You should be returning the promise generated by `userDatabase.get().then(...).then(...).catch(...)`.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, I'm not returning the promise and it's fixed my error.